# How to remove 'GET?' string from URL when submitting a GET form

Tags: html

I'm working on a search feature. When user enters a keyword, they should get a list of brands.

The current URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/brand/list`

If I search for "bag", it should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/brand/list?keyword=bag`

But now, it's `http://127.0.0.1:8000/brand/list/GET?keyword=bag`. I wanna remove the **`GET?`** thing. How can I do this?

```html
<section id="brand-list">
  <form action="GET">
    <input type="text" name="keyword">
    <button>Search</button>
  </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified this as <s>`action="GET"`</s>, this is the URL where the form will submit to, you should specify `method="GET"`, or just nothing, since that is the default method, so:

```
<section id="brand-list">
  <form method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="keyword">
    <button>Search</button>
  </form>
 </section>
```